# exim incorrect substitution count?

Tags: substitute, ex-mode, posix

I'm having strange bevahiour with Vim 9.0

```
$ ex --version | head -3
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Sep 30 2022 03:09:54)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-270
$ VIM_POSIX='cpoptions' ex --clean -u NONE
```

Here is my strange session now

```
Entering Ex mode.  Type "visual" to go to Normal mode.
:i
21 22 23 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
.
:s/23/2z/3p
E488: Trailing characters: p
:s/23/2z/3
21 22 2z 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
:q!
```

The expected result of `s/23/2z/3` is `21 22 23 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 2z 24 25 26 27 28`.
As I'm not sure it's a bug that have been there for years, I'm asking here what option is producing that weird thing.

Regards.

Comment: what exactly are you expecting here?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt see my last words, expected result should be `21 22 23 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 2z 24 25 26 27 28` instead of `21 22 2z 24 25 26 27  18 19 20 21 22 23 24  22 23 24 25 26 27 28`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt also see my comment to accepted answer: I didn't understand the count to be for following lines but third occurrence. Ex is very confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count is a way to extend the number of line considered for substitution

E.g:

```
:1,2s/23/2z/3
```

It is equivalent to:

```
:2,4s/23/2z/
```

In such case the substitution should occurs on the fist occurrence of 23 on the lines 2 to 4 (3 lines) (but not on the third occurrence of 23 on the block of line 1 to 2)

```
:help substitute

When [count] is given,
replace in [count] lines,
starting with the last line in [range].
```

Comment: Thanks. That part of the help (extend the number of line considered for substitution) wasn't clear for me. Plus I was trying to use `ex` in place of `ed` in a box that miss the later but has vim installed with no success for that case, then check back on my Mac. I've reread [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) but that's no clear either about that meaning of the count. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: @gildux perhaps you were thinking of a `sed` where such a count could be used this way?

Comment: yes @D.BenKnoble (in some way) I've never tried such thing directly with `ex`/`vi` before. Even when reading the help, I didn't realised it was that count (I was thinking it's a flag like `g`) Here, I think Bill Joy messed things up :D

Comment: @gildux ed came first…

Comment: Yes, I know that ed came first, that's why I think people that work on ex broke the compatibility. They even have forgoten `G` and `V` (but I think that's because those didn't exist in BSD implementation of `ed` they based their work on…)